# New-AzSqlDatabaseImport never get completed - DatabaseMaxSizeBytes is wrong?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-powershell

I try to import Azure database(including only 1 table) with PowerShell, but it never get completed. I wonder what is wrong? Biggest question concerns values of -DatabaseMaxSizeBytes.

Powershell:

```
$importstatus = New-AzSqlDatabaseImport -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $ServerName `
  -DatabaseName $DatabaseName -StorageKeytype $StorageKeytype -StorageKey $StorageKey -StorageUri $BacpacUri `
  -AdministratorLogin $creds.UserName -AdministratorLoginPassword $creds.Password `
  -Edition GeneralPurpose -ServiceObjectiveName GP_Gen5_2 -DatabaseMaxSizeBytes 1099511627776  #1073741824000

# check status
$importstatus = get-azsqldatabaseimportexportstatus -operationstatuslink $importrequest.operationstatuslink
[console]::write("importing")
while ($importstatus.status -eq "inprogress")
{
    start-sleep -s 10
    $importstatus = get-azsqldatabaseimportexportstatus -operationstatuslink $importrequest.operationstatuslink
    [console]::write(".")
}
[console]::writeline("")
$importstatus
```

Result:

```
Get-AzSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'OperationStatusLink' because it is null.
At C:\Azure\QA_Prod_Copy\Import_sql.ps1:27 char:74
+ ... texportstatus -operationstatuslink $importrequest.operationstatuslink
+                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-AzSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.ImportExport.Cmdlet.GetAzureSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus
 
importing
```

Azure Portal:

```
Azure SQL -> Activity Log -> Import database into the server (Accepted & Started)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$importRequest = New-AzSqlDatabaseImport -ResourceGroupName "resource grp name" -ServerName "server name" -DatabaseName "database name" -StorageKeyType "StorageAccessKey" -StorageKey "storage account access key" -StorageUri "storage ul of bacpac file" -AdministratorLogin "username" -AdministratorLoginPassword $(ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -AsPlainText -Force) -Edition GeneralPurpose -ServiceObjectiveName GP_Gen5_2 -DatabaseMaxSizeBytes 1099511627776

#cheacking status
$importStatus = Get-AzSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -OperationStatusLink $importRequest.OperationStatusLink

[Console]::Write("Importing")
while ($importStatus.Status -eq "InProgress") {
    $importStatus = Get-AzSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -OperationStatusLink $importRequest.OperationStatusLink
    [Console]::Write(".")
    Start-Sleep -s 10
}

[Console]::WriteLine("")
$importStatus
```

Importing database can take some time to complete based on your database size.

Thanks @Osa E [SO Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67216831) for roviding edition with their Maximum Size(in bytes)

***My Execution***

[image]

***Import database completed successfully***

[image]